# Nightwatchjs getvalue of several input

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

Is there any way using **nightwatchjs** to get the value of several inputs?

I need to test the value of several inputs at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get several input values :

First option is callback(not recommend):

```
var text, text2, text3; // ...
browser.getValue('#inputField1', function (result) {
  text = result.value;
  browser.getValue('#inputField2', function (result) {
    text2 = result.value;
    browser.getValue('#inputField3', function (result) {
      text3 = result.value;
      browser.getValue('#inputField4' + text3, function (result) {
        console.log(text, text2, text3) // your code 
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Second , you can use perform() api from document (recommend):

```
var text, text2, text3;
browser
  .getValue('#input', function (result) {
    text = result.value;
    browser.getValue('#inputField2', function (result) {
      text2 = result.value;
    });
  })
  .perform(function () {
    browser.getValue('#inputField3', function (result) {
      console.log(text2, text 1) // they do exist here 
      text3 = result.value;
    });
  });
```

This is docs from nightwatch [Perform](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#perform)

Answer (score 1):

You can use getText or getValue method, example:

```
this.demoTest = function (browser) {
  browser.getText("#main ul li a.first", function(result) {
    this.assert.equal(typeof result, "object");
    this.assert.equal(result.status, 0);
    this.assert.equal(result.value, "nightwatchjs.org");
  });
};

this.demoTest = function (browser) {
  browser.getValue("form.login input[type=text]", function(result) {
    this.assert.equal(typeof result, "object");
    this.assert.equal(result.status, 0);
    this.assert.equal(result.value, "enter username");
  });
};
```

There api documents:[getText API reference](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getText)